# In Vue.js, How to find what data changes cause a component to re-render?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In Vue.js, a component does re-render(update) when some data changes. Sometimes the re-render frequency is too often and i want to find out which data's change cause this re-render. How to find out the changed data causing the re-render?

Comment: Have you seen `updated`: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Comment: @vahdet yes, but in `update` we can't find out which data changes

Comment: Yes, sorry; then, I may suggest adding [watchers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) separately to your data and perform a simple timestamp logging  maybe -with the reactivity assumption that data change will be a trigger for re-render.

Answer (score 6):

Using [deep-diff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff) and a simple watcher, you can easily find the difference between a previous copy of your vm data.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    counter: 0
  },
  mounted() {
    let oldData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$data));
    this.$watch(vm => vm.$data, (newData) => {
      console.log(DeepDiff.diff(oldData, newData));
      oldData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newData));
    }, {
      deep: true
    });
  },
  methods: {
    add: function() {
      this.counter++;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/deep-diff@1/dist/deep-diff.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="add"> +1 </button> {{ counter }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed a simple way. I wonder if vue.js provides some way to do it. I will give a try your method

Comment: I tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to work.  Running Vue's performance mode, I see this one particular component rerendering many, many times.  But I do not get anything from the console

Comment: @MaxCoplan Maybe there is something specific to your code. You should probably open a new question with some sample.

Comment: @Cobaltway unfortunately I cannot share this code, but I will post a new question

Comment: @Cobaltway if you're able to help, I'd really appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876458/how-to-determine-what-causes-components-to-rerender

Comment: I guess `$data` is not the only trigger for component rerendering, there's also properties and potentially other triggers, which are not handled by this snippet, hence it might not be working in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Further to above, and as noted in the comments the deep watcher will only work if the component's own data has changed. A more conclusive method is shown below (also posted to https://stackoverflow.com/a/69275418/960380)

Using the F12 dev tools in Chrome, you can track down what is triggering your component to re-render. Add an updated hook to your component as below:

```
updated() {

            if (!this.updateCnt)
                this.updateCnt = 1;
           
            if (this.updateCnt > 1) { // set to desired
                debugger;
            }
            console.log(`Updated ${this.updateCnt++} times`);
        }
    }
```

Refresh your page in Chrome with F12 tools open and wait for breakpoint to be hit. In the Sources tab, you will see the call stack on the right, with your updated() function as the current stack frame. Look back up the call stack and eventually you should see the code that caused the update to trigger. In my case, it was reactiveSetter() in the vue runtime, which was triggered by me setting a property in a parent component.

Answer (score 0):

Vue 3 and Vue 2.7 supported this natively

```js
export default {
  renderTracked(event) {
    debugger
  },
  renderTriggered(event) {
    debugger
  }
}
```

see https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-in-depth.html#component-debugging-hooks