# Vue/Nuxt Component updates and rerenders without any data changing

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two components, Carousel.vue and Showcase.vue. I'm testing them both in a page like this:

```html
<template>
  <main>
    <app-showcase
      before-focus-class="app-showcase__element--before-focus"
      after-focus-class="app-showcase__element--after-focus"
    >
      <div class="test-showcase" v-for="n in 10" :key="n">
        <img
          class="u-image-cover-center"
          :src="`https://picsum.photos/1000/1000?random=${n}`"
          alt=""
        />
        <div>Showcase numero {{ n }}</div>
      </div>
    </app-showcase>
    <div class="u-layout--main u-margin-vertical--4">
      <div>
        <app-button @click="changeRequestTest(4)">Test Request 4</app-button>
        <app-button @click="changeRequestTest(10)">Test Request 10</app-button>
        <app-carousel
          content-class="u-spread-horizontal--main"
          center
          :request-element="requestTest"
          scroll-by="index"
          @index-change="onIndexChange"
        >
          <template #header>
            <h4>Placeholder images</h4>
            <div>
              Carousel heading h4, showing item number {{ index + 1 }}.
            </div>
          </template>
          <template #default>
            <img
              :src="`https://picsum.photos/100/80?random=${n}`"
              :data-carousel-item-name="n === 10 ? 'giovanni-rana' : ''"
              alt=""
              v-for="n in 20"
              :key="n"
            />
          </template>
        </app-carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      n1: 20,
      n2: 20,
      isAnimationOver: false,
      index: 0,
      requestTest: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeRequestTest(n) {
      this.requestTest = n;
    },
    onIndexChange(e) {
      this.requestTest = e;
    },
    logTest(msg = "hello bro") {
      console.log(msg);
    },
    logElement(e) {
      console.log(e);
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.requestTest = this.$route.query.hero;
  },
};
</script>
```

Both components use a parameter called **index**, which basically registers the position (in the children array) of the element that is being focused/shown/highlighted.

```js
...
data() {
    return {
      index: 0,
      showBackButton: true,
      showForwardButton: true,
      lockScroll: false,
    };
  },
...
```

Carousel actually has a prop, **requestElement**, that allows the carousel to be scrolled to a specific element (via number or element name), and is used in combination with the event "index-change" to update the value in the parent component.

Now that's the problem: every time **requestElement** updates (there is a watcher in Carousel.vue to follow that), the Showcase component rerenders.
That's a huge problem because the Showcase component applies specific classes on the mounted hook, and on rerender, all that classes are lost. I solved the problem by calling my class-applying-methods in the update hook, but I don't particularly like this performance-wise.

Basically, if I remove any reference to requestElement, everything works as intended, but as soon as that value changes, the showcase rerenders completely. I tried to change props/params names, to use dedicated functions instead of inline scripts, nothing works. No common value is shared, neither via props or vuex, so this makes it even weirder.

Any idea why this happens?

**EDIT:** I tried the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50579835/in-vue-js-how-to-find-what-data-changes-cause-a-component-to-re-render/50580381#50580381), as expected no change was detected in Showcase component, but it still gets updated when requestElement is changed in Carousel.

Comment: Could you use the name as the `key`?

Comment: @FrankPl i dont think I understood completely. I tried to key both components with different names, and to use ```requestElement``` as ```key``` value for Carousel. Still triggering update on Showcase (and messing up with Carousel too since it rerenders on key change).